# As3 Position on top based on Y without lag?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, position

I was creating a position script with my own made tag system to position all the objects in order of the y position they have. This script makes my game lag so I wanted to ask if there is a better way of doing this. 
PS: This code is used every frame.

```
private function positionGameObjectToLayer():void 
    {
        var objectOnScreen : Array = [];
        var parentObj : Sprite;
        var l : int;
        l = gameObjects.length;
        for (var i : int = 0; i < l; i++) {
           /*checks if the object has the position tag*/
            if (gameObjects[i].checkTag(Tags.POSITION_ON_Y_TAG)) {  
                objectOnScreen.push(gameObjects[i]); //if it does it goes into this array   
            }
        }
        objectOnScreen.sortOn("y", Array.NUMERIC); /* sorts the array on y position*/
        l = objectOnScreen.length;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            /*this sets the layer of the object in order of the array*/
            parentObj = objectOnScreen[i].parent;
            parentObj.setChildIndex(objectOnScreen[i],parentObj.numChildren - 1); 
        }
        l = gameObjects.length;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
           //if it has the always on top tag
            if (gameObjects[i].checkTag(Tags.POSITION_ON_TOP_TAG)) {
                /*then this code will grab that object and place it over the other layers*/
                parentObj = gameObjects[i].parent;
                parentObj.setChildIndex(gameObjects[i], parentObj.numChildren - 1); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure how much it will help performance, but I'm pretty sure you could achieve the same results with a single loop. How many objects are you iterating over each frame?

Comment: Also, do you need to be processing the always on top ones each frame?

Comment: I think the most important thing here is how big is `gameObjects`?

Comment: GameObject is every game object in the game. Lets say in this case it's a tower defence and has over 50 game objects on screen. Thats how big it is. They change Y position every frame soo.

Comment: How complex is this `checkTag()`? Might I also suggest tracing out some time stamps to console to identify the bottle necks.

Comment: It's a simple loop that checks if the string is in the tags array.

Comment: So I made it now only if 2 objects their art collide this happens. Now if I make it so also if the y pos have changed hat only then it has to check then it would be a ton less heavy